# Как менять значение по скролу?

Tags: javascript

тоесть навели мышкой на div
и крутим колесико  мышки - меняются значения

```js
let initialValue = 50;
```

```css
.box {
  width: 240px;
 height: 80px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">навели мышкой на даннный div и крутим колеско - меняются значения ( минимум 0 , максимум 100). Начальное значение  50</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример того как можно сделать

```js
let cube = document.getElementById('cube')

cube.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", onWheel);

function onWheel(e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

  var info = document.getElementById('delta');

  info.innerHTML = +info.innerHTML + delta;

  e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
}
```

```css
#cube {
  widows: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="cube">cube</div>
    <p id="delta"></p>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: так вроде ж не работает, подержка MozMousePixelScroll слаба

Comment: Можно использовать другие события как wheel

Comment: спасибо, вроде бы ок. Только значения будут от 0 до 100. ( а сейчас можно больше 100.И отрицательные значения тоже) .